# Как в Python c с помощью бибилиотеки Telebot написать код в котором бот будет сравнивать полученный текст с массивом и делать на него ответ?

Tags: python, telebot

Как в Python c с помощью бибилиотеки Telebot написать код в котором бот будет сравнивать полученный текст с массивом и делать на него ответ?

Comment: Ну как-как. Можно сидя за компьютером, некоторые любят работать стоя. Но точно все сначала читают какие-то книги, учат язык и инструмент -  в том числе библиотеку Telebot, а уж потом начинают писать код. Сначала простенькие упражнения, потом -  упражнения посложнее. А уж потом какие-то задачки пытаются решить. А вы хотите в обратном порядке? И вы ожидали, что тут вам по вашему велению сейчас выкатят готовый код?

Comment: веления...не хотите не отвечайте, мне то что...

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос слишком объемный для ответа на данном сайте. Кроме того, судя по комментарию автора "не отвечайте, мне то что" (правописание автора) ему ответ и не нужен, подразумевается, что он больше нужен отвечающим или кому-то другому.

Comment: @Сергей не знаю откуда у вас такие выводы, вы не правы

Comment: Примерно такие же выводы ещё у четырех человек. Но будет интересно знать, как вы трактуете ваше  "не отвечайте, мне то что"

Comment: @Сергей если мой вопрос не подходит под политику форума, стоит сказать сразу нормальным языком, а не вот это все. Может я и глуп, но это не означает что со мной стоит общаться также глупыми манерами.

Comment: На будущее: приходя на новый сайт с просьбой помочь, читайте его правила. И старайтесь отвечать на комментарии хоть относительно разумно. Но это просто рекомендация, "мне то что", что вам не ответят:-)

Comment: @Сергей благодарю, интересно, python же высокоуровневый язык и нету простого метода в несколько строк с задействованием может быть какой-то библиотеки что-бы решить задачу?

Comment: Я не знаю Telebot, он мне не нужен. Но каким бы язык не был высокоуровневым, такие задачи парой фраз не объясняются. Если же это просто, то откройте документацию по библиотеке. Судя же по последнему сообщению, вы вообще не знаете Python. Тогда лучше такие вопросы задавать не на этом сайте. Предлагаю на этом закончить обсуждение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так наверное

```
list_data = ["1", "2",...]

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text in list_data)
def hanle(message: types.Message):
    ...
```